# Type conversion error while using Linq to XML

Tags: c#-4.0

I have created a sample XML. And trying to Read by using LINQ

here is the code:

```
  XElement root =  XElement.Load("C:\\............\\TestData.xml");
  IEnumerable<Xelement> address = from tt in root.Elements("Test")
  select tt;
```

I am getting compile time error at select statement :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' 
    to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EvalTest.Xelement>'. 
    An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestData>
    <Test Method="1">
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Submitter> Ritvij</Submitter>
        <Date>11/5/2013 2:51:57 PM </Date>
    </Test>
    <Test Method="2">
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Submitter> Ritvij</Submitter>
        <Date>11/5/2013 2:51:57 PM </Date>
    </Test>
</TestData>
```

Answer (score 0):

`root.Elements` returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` (with a capital "E"), but you're trying to assign it to `IEnumerable<Xelement>` (lower case "e").

Either modify your code to use `XElement` or use `var`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> address = from tt in root.Elements("Test") select tt;
```

```
var address = from tt in root.Elements("Test") select tt;
```